# I am using SQL Server 2012 and it's working fine. but SQL Server 2008 and it's not working. while i am run the query i am getting this error:

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012 and it's working fine. but in SQL Server 2008 unfortunately it's not working.

while i am running  the query, i am getting this error:

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2 'CONCAT' is not a recognized
>   built-in function name

```sql
SELECT  CONCAT(CCYYMM, RIGHT(c.AMT001, 2)) ACCDAT,
        CSTCOD,
        PRPCOD,
        c.RevenueAmount,
        D.RevenueAllowance,
        OUTLET,
        AMTYTD,
        ALWYTD,
        MODCOD,
        RECTYP,
        RECCOD,
        GRPCOD,
        DEPCOD,
        [CSTCTR],
        [GLCODE]
FROM    PMS.FMNASTBL
        CROSS APPLY ( VALUES ( 'AMT001', AMT001 ) ) c (AMT001, RevenueAmount)
        CROSS APPLY ( VALUES ( 'ALW001', ALW001 ) ) D (ALW001, RevenueAllowance);
```

Comment: SAME QUERY I AM USING SQL SERVER 2012 AND IT'S WORKING FINE.   BUT SQL SERVER 2008 AND IT'S NOT WORKING.    WHILE I AM RUN THE QUERY I AM GETTING THIS ERROR (Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? ANSI SQL has `||` for concatenation. `CONCAT()` is product specific...

Comment: SQL Server also has `+` for concatenation.

Comment: THAT QUERY IT'S WORKING ON 2012 BUT 2008 IS NOT WORKING

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CONCAT() function is available from SQL Server version 2012 onwards. It is not supported in older versions.

In older versions, use +

```
SELECT
            cast(CCYYMM as varchar(10)+cast(RIGHT(C.AMT001,2) as varchar(2))as ACCDAT
            ,CSTCOD
            ,PRPCOD
            ,C.RevenueAmount
            ,D.RevenueAllowance
            ,OUTLET
            ,AMTYTD
            ,ALWYTD
            ,MODCOD
            ,RECTYP
            ,RECCOD
            ,GRPCOD
            ,DEPCOD
            ,[CSTCTR]
            ,[GLCODE]    
        FROM PMS.FMNASTBL
            CROSS APPLY
            (
              VALUES
                ('AMT001',AMT001 )
            ) c (AMT001,RevenueAmount)
            CROSS APPLY
            (
              VALUES
                ('ALW001',ALW001 )
            ) D (ALW001,RevenueAllowance)
```

Comment: Don't forget to tell OP that `+` works in older SQL Server versions!

Comment: @jarlh Thanks. Done :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use "+" to append strings since CONCAT() function is not available in version older than 2012.

Comment: SO WHAT I HAVE TO DO PLEASE HELP ME